# how to set array element/sort array in php

Tags: php, smarty

Hello All i want to sort the array in the way that

ASC order of user id

there is array like $user

i want to sort on the base

id $user['role'] =1;

then that element will set at the top of the array

Comment: Is this a regular php array? Providing an example of the entire array (not a single element) would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Look in the PHP manual at asort, sort, and ksort. I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but one of them is bound to do what you need.

Comment: And if these don't then usort will, provided you write a correct callback function.

Answer (score 0):

Does that information come from a database? In that case, doing something like `ORDER BY role DESC, user_id` would be better than having PHP sort it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If your array example $user['role'] = 1 means that 1 is the user id you want to use [sort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)($user); however if role is going to be numeric you would want [asort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)($user); instead as sort will overwrite numeric keys.  As @Rob above said you may want to use [ksort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) but only if you are making the array $user[user_id] = role.

Hope this helps

Regards

Luke

Answer (score -1):

Thanx All For Replying on my question

i got the solution here it is

```
function compare($a,$b)
{
    return strcmp($a["role"]['ID'], $b["role"]['ID']);
}
usort($a,compare);
```